# Magento 2 url key includes SKU number, how to remove?

Tags: magento2, sku, .htaccess, url-key

The big problem with Magento somehow amending the url key to include the SKU where

/product-title-stec00778.html

should be

/product-title.html

and the SKU is

SKU STEC00778

Any ideas? Not sure if I can handle via .htaccess or how?

Answer (score 0):

In both Magento 1.x and 2.x you can change the URL key field from admin itself.

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

You can change url that product by configure:

Admin Panel > CATALOG > select Products > select your product > select tab Search Engine Optimization > URL Key > change your url > Save

I hope it help you.